# $sum retornando valor 0

Tags: mongodb, sum

Criei a base de dados e preencho um coleção 'estoque' como na figura em anexo.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estava tentando realizar a soma das quantidade de itens do estoque, mas o Mongo só me retorna o valor 0 (zero).
Usei o seguinte comando:

db.estoque.aggregate({$group:{_id:null, soma:{$sum:'quantidade'}}})

O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Coloque um "$" antes do quantidade. {$sum:'$quantidade'}

Answer (score 0):

Como você quer usar um campo de seu `document` no `aggregate`, você precisá colocar o prefixo `$`, ficando `$quantidade`.

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-field-path) do MongoDB:

> **field path**
>
> Path to a field in the document. To specify a field path,
>   use a string that prefixes the field name with a dollar sign ($).

Sua query ficará da seguinte maneira:

```
db.estoque.aggregate({$group:{_id:null, soma:{$sum:'$quantidade'}}})
```

Comment: Nossa, era só isso mesmo. Brigadão! \o/